# How do I automatically remove spaces from a path in the blog module

Tags: nodes

Some places on the site are correct
e.g.  http://groundhogresearch.com/blogs/bob-schweickert-jr
but the blog module block show this path
http://groundhogresearch.com/blogs/Bob%20Schweickert%20Jr. which of course can't be found

Comment: I have PathAuto installed.  It has been working fine for months.  I recently installed the Blog Module and it doesn't work for the items in the Blog Archive, Top Blog Authors blocks.

Comment: PathAuto has already been configured and works fine for all urls on my site except the urls used by the newly installed  Blog Module (multi user).

Drupal's "Recent blog posts block" even urls work OK.  It is just the urls in new "Blog Archive" and "Top Blog Authors" blocks that are not processed by PathAuto.

I get:
http://groundhogresearch.com/blogs/Bob%20Schweickert%20Jr.

Comment: With them I get:
http://groundhogresearch.com/blogs/Bob%20Schweickert%20Jr.

instead of the cleaned up
http://groundhogresearch.com/blogs/bob-schweickert-jr

Comment: None of these answers address the actual question.

Answer (score 1):

Using [Pathauto](https://drupal.org/project/pathauto) you can replace spaces with a character of your choice (and do a lot of other stuff too), like for example a dash. Once you have enabled the module go to `admin/config/search/path/settings` and start configuring the module.

Answer (score 0):

As you have already installed [PathAuto moduel](https://drupal.org/project/pathauto), Navigate to     `admin/config/search/path/settings` and change the `Word separator` for your URL.

[image: pathauto settings]

Answer (score -1):

You can use Pathauto to configure that kind of behaviour.